# One if statement for multiple controls?

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know if you can use one general if statement for the same condition but on multiple controls?

for example, If I have five labels and I want each label to say "hello" when I push a button I would write something like

```
If Label1.Text = "" Then
     Label1.Text = "hello"
End If
```

But instead of writing an if statement for each label is there a way to apply this one if statement to all five labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can iterate over all controls in a form, but you'd need to restrict them to `Label` instances, fortunately LINQ makes this easy:

```
Dim emptyLabels As IEnumerable(Of Label) = _
    Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)().Where(Function(l) l.Text.Length = 0)

For Each label As Label In emptyLabels
    label.Text = "hello"
Next
```

Comment: Next time, don't be lazy - http://converter.telerik.com/. BTW, your original code didn't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
Dim ifEmptyAssignHello As Action(Of Label) = _
    Sub(l)
        If l.Text = "" Then
            l.Text = "Hello"
        End If
    End Sub

ifEmptyAssignHello(Label1)
ifEmptyAssignHello(Label2)
ifEmptyAssignHello(Label3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could

- make a method which takes a label,
- then pass labels into it.

  ```
  Public Sub SayHello(l As Label)
     If (l is Nothing) Then Return

     If (l.Text = "") Then
         l.Text = "Hello"
     End If
  End Sub

  ...

  For Each l As Label in anyLabels
     SayHello(l)
  End For
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The most concise way to do what you describe is to iterate over an explicit array of the labels. VB.Net will notice that they're all `Label`s and figure out the type for you.

```
For Each individualLabel In {Label1, 
                             Label2, 
                             Label3, 
                             Label4, 
                             Label5}

    If individualLabel.Text = "" Then individualLabel.Text = "hello"

Next
```

Of course, if you need to do this more than once, you'll want to define a variable to refer to that particular group of five labels.

```
Dim myFiveLabels As IEnumerable(Of Label) = {Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4, Label5}
```

(We explicitly define the variable as an `IEnumerable` because this way it can *only* be used to iterate over each element of the group. If it were defined as an `Array` or `List`, you could e.g. add / remove elements and generally complicate its behaviour.)